# Javascript cookie to save user preference and display content using the shared preference?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I need a solution based on java script(cookies), which could save the user selected preferences and render the output(html pages) acc. to the cookie saved.

Here is the situation:

Lets say user starts from page1 and navigates to page2(having 40-50 hyperlinks) and there he selects or clicks one of the hyperlink and get directed to the target page(there will be 40-50 pages corresponding to those 40-50 links).

So all i need is to automate the whole process, so that after first visit user's selection could get saved and he will directly get navigated to final target(It will be one of the page from 40-50 pages).

Any code-snippet will highly be appreciated..

mrana

Comment: Have you tried to search for "work with cookies in javascript"? Google gives 17 million results, StackOverflow gives more than 2000 questions (and answers) regarding this.

Comment: ok, provide the link which could resembles with my issue...

Answer (score 0):

I am curious to know why can't you do this in a `preference` table on the server side. Cookies can be removed from the browser (which would force users to go through that step again) and storing 40-50 cookies in the browser is not a good solution, as cookies get transmitted to every HTTP request so it would waste users' bandwidth.

If you have these settings/preferences stored on the server side then you can easily determine where to send the user when he logs in to your site, instead of extracting those information from the cookies.

Alternatively you can store these preferences in `localStorage` which provides bigger storage for storing key/values. The downside is that you need to load a bootstrap JS first which will read the settings from `localStorage` and decide where to redirect the user.

But IMHO I'd still go with a server side solution if I have to store 40-50 preferences.

Note: Cookies can only have 4KB of data, this is a limit.